# How can I convert a DateTime variable in a LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datetime

Given this expression:

```
var q = (from c in db.ContattiTitoliStudio
                     where ...
                     orderby c.Data descending
                     select new
                     {
                         c.ID,
                         Date = c.Data.ToString("MM dd, YYYY"),
                     });
```

`c.Data is nullable`, but also with a non-nullable var is the same:
"`...No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments...`"

I tried `nullable`, not nullable, with `(c.Data!=null)...`, with `String.Format`, with `DateTime.Parse`, etc... But I can't format `c.Date` the way I want.

In SQL Server I use `datetime` as the type.

If I use normal `Date = c.Date` this will be displayed as "01/01/2011 0.0.00".

Comment: What is the declared type of `ContattiTitoliStudio.Data`?

Comment: I usually find it's best to keep things as dates/datetimes (rather than formatting as strings) for as long as possible - do you really need it in a string format before it's actually output on the page?

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Comment: in my db ContattiTitoliStudio.Data is date, not datetime and this linq is for repeater that display date in my format...

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,finally this is the solution:

```
var test= from e in db.Employees.ToList() select new {Time= e.Date.ToString()};
```

from msdn forums:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/208396f4-0406-41c6-b55f-0d8bb5d14b2c

Answer (score 1):

Make use of **Nullable(i.e ?? operator)** Operation which is exists in C#

```
var q = (from c in db.ContattiTitoliStudio
                     where ...
                     orderby c.Data descending
                     select new
                     {
                         c.ID,
                         Date = (c.Data ?? DateTime.MinValue).ToString("MM dd, YYYY"),
                     });
```

**Note : DateTime.MinValue is used when the value of c.Data is null which used to avoid null**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
Date = c.Data.HasValue ? c.Data.Value.ToString("MM dd, YYYY") : string.Empty
```

Comment: Beware null reference exception!

Comment: Well aware :) I'll add it anyway for his sake.

Comment: always same error ..."No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments..."

Comment: Are you sure the value of Data.Value is a DateTime?

Comment: if Data is nullable i have this:
No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments.

if Data is nullable = false o have this:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Data is DateTime type....

i don't understand why....

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us, but I'm guessing that `ContattiTitoliStudio.Data` is `Nullable<DateTime>`. In this case, you should say

```
Date = c.Data.HasValue ? "null" : c.Data.Value.ToString("MM dd, YYYY")
```